# Can anyone tell me why these methods are not running after the first method call? - Java

Tags: java, sockets, arraylist, methods, client-server

so basically I have a simple echo server client. What i am wanting to do is run the server then run the client, once the client has been run it should run the methods within it. However, only the first method searchForSkill runs and after this nothing else happens can anyone explain why this is happening or how to ensure the next method called actually runs? I have a developer database class which uses a constructor to create the objects held in the server class. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Server class:

```
      import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;



public class Server {



    static List<DeveloperDatabase> list = new ArrayList<DeveloperDatabase>(){

        {
            add(new DeveloperDatabase(1,"David Ferguson", "Java", true));
            add(new DeveloperDatabase(2,"Grant Thompson", "Java", true));
            add(new DeveloperDatabase(3,"Craig Jackson", "C++", true));
            add(new DeveloperDatabase(4,"Kevin James","C++", true));
            add(new DeveloperDatabase(5,"Greg Troupe", "Python", true));
            add(new DeveloperDatabase(6,"James Smith", "Python", true));
            add(new DeveloperDatabase(7,"Jamie Richie", "PHP", true));
            add(new DeveloperDatabase(8,"Rory McGrattan", "PHP", false));
        }

    };
    public static String printJava(){
        String message="";
        for (int i=0;i<2;i++){
            message +=list.get(i).toString();
            message+=" \n";

        }
        return message;
    }
    public static String printC(){
        String message="";
        for (int i=2;i<4;i++){
            message +=list.get(i).toString();
            message+=" \n";

        }
        return message;
    }
    public static String printPy(){
        String message="";
        for (int i=4;i<6;i++){
            message +=list.get(i).toString();
            message+=" \n";

        }
        return message;
    }
    public static String printPHP(){
        String message="";
        for (int i=6;i<8;i++){
            message +=list.get(i).toString();
            message+=" \n";

        }
        return message;
    }

    // Main
    public static void main(String[] args) {


        ServerSocket listenSocket;
        Socket s;

        PrintWriter toClient = null;
        Scanner fromClient = null;

        int port;                       // holds port server will listen on
        String userInput;               // holds a line typed by the user

        System.out.print("Server - port to listen on: ");
        //port = stdIn.nextInt();       // get port number from user
        port = 4444;                    // get port number from user
        System.out.println(port);


        try {
            listenSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
            System.out.println("Waiting for client...");
            s = listenSocket.accept();

            toClient = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(), true);
            fromClient = new Scanner(s.getInputStream());

            int inputLine;
            do {
                inputLine = fromClient.nextInt();


                switch (inputLine) {
                    case 1: // get skills
                    {
                        System.out.println("GET skill");
                        fromClient.nextLine();
                        String quoteNum = fromClient.nextLine();//receive from client
                        if (quoteNum.equalsIgnoreCase("Java")) {
                            toClient.println(printJava());
                        } else if (quoteNum.equalsIgnoreCase("C++")) {
                            toClient.println(printC());
                        } else if (quoteNum.equalsIgnoreCase("Python")) {
                            toClient.println(printPy());
                        } else if (quoteNum.equalsIgnoreCase("PHP")) {
                            toClient.println(printPHP());
                        }
                        else {
                            toClient.println("No developer with those skills found");
                        }
                        // toClient.println(list.equals("Java"));//number -1 for array (0) to client print
                        System.out.println("Pushed Developer number: " + quoteNum + " to client at " + s.getInetAddress());
                        //toClient.println(quotes[quoteNum]); // return quote          //if "java' { get(0)   get(1)
                        break;
                    }
                    case 2: // add quote
                    {
                        System.out.println("ADD Developer to System");
                        fromClient.nextLine();   // flush newline
                        String quote = fromClient.next();
                        fromClient.nextLine();
                        String quote1 = fromClient.next();
                        fromClient.nextLine();
                        boolean quote2 = fromClient.nextBoolean();
                        toClient.println("The\t*************Developer has been Added to the Developer Database********");
                        list.add(new DeveloperDatabase(9, quote, quote1, quote2));
                        toClient.println(list.get(8).toString());
                        //addDeveloper(quote,quote1,quote2);
                        System.out.println(list.get(8));
                        //System.out.println("Received quote from client:" + quote);
                        quote = quote + "\n\n";
                        //list.add((quote);
                        System.out.println("Added Developer: " + quote);
                        break;
                    }
                    case 3: // Check if Developer is available
                    {
                        System.out.println("Check if developer is Available\n");
                        fromClient.nextLine();
                        String quoteNum = fromClient.nextLine();
                        System.out.println("Checking availability for: " + quoteNum);
                        if (quoteNum.equalsIgnoreCase("Rory McGrattan")) {
                            toClient.println("The Developer is not available for hire");
                        } else {
                            toClient.println("The Developer is available for hire");
                        }break;
                    }case 4: {
                        System.out.println("Hire A Developer");
                        String quoteNum =fromClient.next();
                        System.out.println("Client wants to hire: "+quoteNum);
                        String message = quoteNum;
                        for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
                            if (quoteNum.equalsIgnoreCase(list.get(i).getDeveloperName())){
                                list.get(i).hireDeveloper();
                            }//if
                        }//if
                        //System.out.println(message);
                        toClient.println("******* You have Hired: "+ message+" ********");
                        break;
                    }
                    case 5: {// Print all Developers
                        String message="";
                        for (int i=0;i<8;i++){
                            message +=list.get(i).toString();
                            message+=" \n";
                        }
                        toClient.println(message);
                    }
                    default:
                        break;

                }

            } while (fromClient.hasNextLine());

            // Close all streams
            System.out.println("Closing Server...");
            toClient.close();
            fromClient.close();
            s.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception: " + e);
            System.exit(1);
        }
    } // run


} // Server
```

Client class:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Client {
    static Scanner stdIn = new Scanner(System.in);
    static PrintWriter toServer = null; // output stream to remote host
    static Scanner fromServer = null;   // input stream from remote host
    static String reply;// holds reply from remote host

public static void doTasks(){
    searchForSkill("PHP");

    addDeveloper("David Blaine", "Java", true);
    checkAvailability("David Ferguson");
    hireDeveloper("Thompson");
    printAllDevelopers();


}

    private static void searchForSkill(String skill) {
        toServer.println(1);
        String quoteNum = "php"; //Search for a specific coding language - Specific to the entered parameters
        System.out.println("Searching for Skill: " + skill + " in Developer Database");
        toServer.println(quoteNum);
        while (!(reply = fromServer.nextLine()).isEmpty()) {
            // System.out.println(reply1);
            System.out.println(reply);// print reply to screen
        }
        fromServer.nextLine();     // Consume the newline
        System.out.println();

    }
    public static void addDeveloper(String name, String skill,boolean hire) {
        toServer.println(2);
        System.out.println("Add Developer to system ");
        stdIn.nextLine();   // flush newline
        String quoteString = name;//stdIn.nextLine();
        String quoteString1 = skill;//stdIn.nextLine();
        boolean quoteString2 = hire;//stdIn.nextLine();
        toServer.println(quoteString);
        toServer.println(quoteString1);
        toServer.println(quoteString2);
        fromServer.next();
        System.out.println("\nDeveloper entered: " + quoteString + "\n");
        while (!(reply = fromServer.nextLine()).isEmpty()) {
            // System.out.println(reply1);
            System.out.println(reply);// print reply to screen
        }
    }
    public static void checkAvailability(String developerName) {
        try {
            toServer.println(3);
            System.out.println("Send Developer Name to Find Availability: ");
            String quoteDel = developerName;
            toServer.println(quoteDel);
            while (!(reply = fromServer.nextLine()).isEmpty()) {
                // System.out.println(reply1);
                System.out.println(reply);// print reply to screen
            }
        } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
        }
    }

    public static void hireDeveloper(String name) {
        toServer.println(4);
        String quoteNum = name; //Search for a specific coding language - Specific to the entered parameters
        System.out.println("Searching for: " + name + " in Developer Database");
        toServer.println(quoteNum);
        while (!(reply = fromServer.nextLine()).isEmpty()) {
            // System.out.println(reply1);
            System.out.println(reply);// print reply to screen
        }
        fromServer.nextLine();     // Consume the newline
        System.out.println();

    }

    public static void printAllDevelopers(){
        toServer.println(5);
        while (!(reply = fromServer.nextLine()).isEmpty()) {
            // System.out.println(reply1);
            System.out.println(reply);// print reply to screen
        }
        fromServer.nextLine();     // Consume the newline
        System.out.println();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Socket serverSocket = null;  // holds the Socket object
        String remoteServer = "localhost"; // remote host is 'local'!

        int port;

        try {
            System.out.print("Server port: ");
            //port = stdIn.nextInt();     // get port number from user
            port = 4444;     // get port number from user
            System.out.print(port);
            System.out.println("\n");

            // Try to connect to remote host machine on port xxxx
            serverSocket = new Socket(remoteServer, port);
            // Set up the input/output streams to the remote host
            toServer = new PrintWriter(serverSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
            // Convert the socket's input stream to a 'Scanner'
            // to allow 'nextLine' operations to be performed
            fromServer = new Scanner(serverSocket.getInputStream());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Exception: " + e);
            System.exit(1);
        } // try-catch

        String userInput;                       // holds a line typed by the user
        String name;                            // to store name
        String number;                          // to store phone number

        do {
            userInput = "c";
            searchForSkill("PHP");
            addDeveloper("David Blaine","Java",true);
            checkAvailability("Jamie Richie");
            hireDeveloper("Jamie Richie");
            printAllDevelopers();
            //stdIn.nextLine();         // get command from user
        } while (!userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("x"));



        toServer.println(userInput);

        // Close all streams
        toServer.close();
        fromServer.close();
        stdIn.close();
        serverSocket.close();

    } // main
} // Client
```

Developer Database class:

```
/**
 * Created by ${Grant} on ${28/09/2017}
 * COMMENTS ABOUT PROGRAM HERE
 */
public class DeveloperDatabase {
    private  int id;
    private  String developerName;
    private  String codingLanguage;
    private  boolean freeForHire;

    public  DeveloperDatabase(){

    }

    public  DeveloperDatabase(int id,String name,String codeSkills,boolean hire){
        this.id = id;
        this.developerName = name;
        this.codingLanguage=codeSkills;
        this.freeForHire=hire;
    }


    public String toString() {
        String message = "\tName: " +developerName;
        message += "\n" + "\tCoding Language:  "+ codingLanguage+"\n";

        if (freeForHire== true) {
            message += "\tThe developer is Available! for Hire!\n";
        } else {
            message += "\tThe developer is not Available for Hire!\n";
        }

        return message;
    }//toString


    public boolean getFreeForHire() {

        if (freeForHire==true){
            System.out.println("The Developer is free to hire!");
        }else{
            System.out.println("The Developer is not free to hire!");
        }
        return freeForHire;

    }

    public  String getCodingLanguage() {
        return codingLanguage;
    }

    public void hireDeveloper(){
        if (freeForHire==true)
            freeForHire = false;
        System.out.println(developerName +" is Hired!");
    }

    public String getDeveloperName() {
        return developerName;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }//main
}//class
```

Comment: Please consider revising the code sample you posted in this question. As it currently stands, its formatting and scope make it hard for us to help you; here is a [great resource](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to get you started on that.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca - is there any particular class that you feel needs reformatted? I mean basically what is happening is the server is run the then the client, the client then calls the searchForSkills method which sends a 1 to the server which enters the switch statement and runs that case - returning the information back to the client - this information is received by the client again in the searchForSkills method -

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca -  i believe that the problem may lie with the line - while (!(reply = fromServer.nextLine()).isEmpty()) {
            // System.out.println(reply1);
            System.out.println(reply);// print reply to screen
        }                                                                                                             Once it gets to this line in searchForSkills i do not believe it is able to leave which then means it cannot go on to the next method

Answer (score 0):

```
while (!(reply = fromServer.nextLine()).isEmpty()) {
    // System.out.println(reply1);
    System.out.println(reply);// print reply to screen
}
```

You are receiving a response, stopping you from exiting the `while` loop.

Comment: Thanks for your response Frederik, I have done what you said however, once i have done this it gets stuck on the line -        System.out.println("Searching for Skill: " + skill + " in Developer Database"); - within the searchForSkill method - any ideas? thanks

Comment: Any ideas Frederik?

Comment: @GrantTroupe With "it gets stuck", do you mean that execution actually stops or just that your new (adjusted) while condition isn't true? Debugging is your friend ;)

Comment: It prints the line Searching for Skill: PHP in Developer Database and then completely skips the while loop within the searchForSkills method

Comment: Ok so then the issue is still in your while condition, only now it doesn't get executed instead of not getting exited. Explain the logic that you're looking at out loud and see if your coin drops :)

Comment: I changed the while condition to - while(fromServer.hasNext()){
            System.out.println(fromServer.nextLine());
        } - this works and prints out the correct information however the same thing happens with this while loop - it never exits - must it think there is still data to read fromServer? or think it still has next? is there a way to get around this